# how to use a delete modal with php and json

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I want to use a delete modal popup before the data delete or not. I tried with bootstrap modal and it doesn't work. Then I pass my data with delete button, but I want to a popup window before delete the details.

I tried this without any popup window. This deletes data when button clicks. This is my detail from view delete button.

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="update.php?id=<?php echo $value['id'];?>&firstname=<?php echo $value['firstname'];?>&lastname=<?php echo $value['lastname'];?>&age=<?php echo $value['age'];?>" role="button" id="delete" style="margin-left: 10px;">Delete</a>
```

I want to do when this button clicks modal popup and ask whether this wants to delete or not. I tried with this bootstrap modal.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Delete
</button>    
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How to correct my code with this modal. Can anyone help me. I want when the modal yes button clicks then delete the data.

Comment: attach the trigger to the save changes part of your modal

Comment: i added that but not working

Comment: What did you add and what did not work?

Comment: what means you trigger. i added data-toggle and data-target to toggle button.can you show me the fixed code

Comment: What you can do here is use ajax to process the delete after the modal is closed.

Comment: i want to redirect my update functions have in update.php

Comment: Small typo improvements.

Comment: you have to put the link to the update php in the modal button (on yes click) and not in the link that opens the modal. There you should only pass the data to identify the record to be deleted